# I'm having problems using DatePicker with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm having problems using DatePicker with react native
when I'm using it, there are an error like this:
render error a date or time must be specified as value prop
my repository:  [my github repository](https://github.com/weslley281/baobabrasil.git)

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

function changeDate(selectDate) {
    if (event?.type === 'dismissed') {
      setDate(date);
      return;
    }
    setDate(selectDate);
  }

<DatePicker
  format="DD/MM/YYY"
  date={date}
  onDateChange={changeDate}
 />
```

Comment: This line is unnecessary: `setDate(date);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `value` prop instead of `date`

```
<DatePicker format="DD/MM/YYY" value={date} onDateChange={changeDate} />
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work

```
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
    
    const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
            setShowDate(false);

    
    if (event?.type === 'dismissed') {
        setDate(date);
        return;
    }
    setDate(selectedDate);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong prop for the initial date it's `value` not `date`

and you also don't need to set a date that is already set

```js
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

function changeDate(selectDate) {
    if (event?.type === 'dismissed') {
      return;
    }
    setDate(selectDate);
  }

<DatePicker
  format="DD/MM/YYY"
  value={date}
  onDateChange={changeDate}
 />
```